# Android Firebase Push Notification Bundle data issue

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

After sending a notification to my application then when I tap to the notification bar it goes to the MainActivity with Bundle data.

But after exit from the application then when I enter the application by tapping app_launcher_icon the application gets the previous notification Bundle data.

Now how to solve this issue.

Comment: can you show your code of notification receiver and mainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Clear your intent data after you consume it

```
getIntent().setData(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send the data from the receiver to the activity by  intent put extra .